# Making dijkstra algorithm Shortest Path with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am new user of ArcGIS. I have some basic knowledge such as, add data as layers, find and download map as my related study, I am also familiar with common tools in ArcGIS like joining and selection tools.

As student in a class, I have an assignment to make shortest path using dijkstra algorithm in one week. Even I do this in short time, I have further interest to learn more about GIS field. Unfortunately I don't know which step that I have to take to study especially for finish my assignment. I have search study material in internet but they have further implementation and lack of basic knowledge

**Is there any references from basic practical knowledge to make shortest path analysis with dijkstra algorithm with ArcGIS map software?**

After this I look further to use this analysis to make shortest path analysis with dijkstra algorithm to handle flood as disaster management.

Answer (score 1):

Dikstra algorithm is already implemented in ArcGIS for two extensions :

- Network analyst, which works on vector-based network
- Spatial analyst, which works with raster (cost distance)

If you want to make your own implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm, I think that the best way is to start working with python. Follow the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) to build it.